# How to get an Id (int) using Linq or Lambda based on condition in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Lets consider following data table:

```
Id      Name     PhoneNo
1       Sam      123654
2       Mike     213654
3       John     998745
```

I need the Id of Mike from this list of data and return as int value. I retrieve  all these data from database as list of item using AllTestViews method.

```
  int id= gateway.AllTestViews().//Something//(a => a.TestName=="Mike")
    return id;
```

Is there any way to get this id or i have to use sql query for this issue?
Thanks

Comment: @Rahul Singh has the right answer for this question. Using `Where` and `Select` should only be used to return collections instead of single objects. For instance `.Where(i => i.Id < 4).Select(i => i.ID)` would return `{1, 2, 3}`

@Ian's answer only works for this particular case

Comment: @LuisLavieri you are right. Actually I didn't notice that he has edited his answer. His first answer not worked as i am not working in C#06. of course Thanks Rahul for his answer as well as explanation.

Comment: You can still change the answer. He is right at the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `Where` filter chained with `Select` (to get the IDs) like this:

```
 var result = gateway.Where(x => x.TestName == something).Select(x => x.ID);
```

Note: you only need to adjust the condition above (`x.TestName == something`) to the condition filter which fits your need.

Answer (score 5):

Use `FirstOrDefault`:-

```
int result = gateway.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Mike")?.ID ?? 0;
```

If you are not using C# 6, then you need to check for nulls before accessing Id:-

```
var firstObj= geteway.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Mike");
if(firstObj != null)
{
    //fetch Id
}
```

Comment: Need a double equals there bro